# I want to retrieve information from database on onkeyup event and show it in text boxes using jquery

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql

Here on stackoverflow I've found many programs but none of them shows how to place the retrieved result from database into textboxes......

My code is as follows:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
$(function(){
  $(".search").keyup(function() {
  var searchid = $(this).val();
  var dataString = 'search='+ searchid;
  if(searchid!='') {
    $.ajax({ 
      type: "POST",
      url: "upload.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(html) {
        $("#result").html(html).show();
      }
    });
  }
  return false;
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Center:
<input type="text" name="center" class="search"></p>
<p>username:
<input type="text" name="username" id="searchid"></p>
<p>Password:
<input type="text" name="password"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Database table:

```
create table user(
center int(10),
username varchar(10),
password varchar(10),
primary key(center)
)
```

Now I want that when I enter the information in the first text box, I should get username and password in the next 2 text boxes from MySql database. What to do ?

Comment: Request the data from server, select inputs using jQuery, set values using `val` method.

Comment: Can you write the code for me in detail.....?

Comment: How to request data from a server ?

Comment: What runs on your server? Do you have an interface defined?

Comment: I've linux server...php is installed over it...and mysql...I'm not abl to understand jquery and ajax to send and request the required data from adatabase. What I've got so far is this code which is not  working. $(function(){
$(".search").keyup(function() 
{ 
var searchid = $(this).val();
var dataString = 'search='+ searchid;
if(searchid!='')
{
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "upload.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
    $("#result").html(html).show();
    }
    });
}return false;    
});

Comment: @PrakashPatil use the **Edit** button below your question to put your comment and add the code snippet. It will help you get answers

Answer (score 0):

You've almost got it. A few pointers:

(1) You need to have the javascript/jQuery code inside `<script>` tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $(".search").keyup(function() {
      var searchid = $(this).val();
      var dataString = 'search='+ searchid;
      if(searchid!='') {
        $.ajax({ 
          type: "POST",
          url: "upload.php",
          data: dataString,
          cache: false,
          success: function(html) {
            $("#result").html(html).show();
          }
        });
      }
      return false;
    });
</script>
```

(2) You need to have the `upload.php` file in the web root, and it should look something like this:

```
<?php

$srx = $_POST['search'];

//Do your MySQL search here, something like:
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` LIKE '$search' LIMIT 1");

$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$un = $data['username'];
$pw = $data['password'];

echo $un .'|'. $pw;
```

Since you are expecting HTML, I joined the username|password using a `|` character. You can also send it as JSON, but that is a bit more complicated.

Now, in your AJAX success function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $(".search").keyup(function() {
      var searchid = $(this).val();
      var dataString = 'search='+ searchid;
      if(searchid!='') {
        $.ajax({ 
          type: "POST",
          url: "upload.php",
          data: dataString,
          cache: false,
          success: function(html) {
            var data = html.split['|'];
            var un = data[0];
            var pw = data[1];
            $("#searchid").val(un);
            $("#password").val(pw);
          }
        });
      }
      return false;
    });
</script>
```

**Here's How It Works:**

(a) The PHP file echoes out searched data: "Bob Jones|mypass"

(b) The AJAX success function receives that as `html = "Bob Jones|mypass";`

(c) Therefore, you can `split()` that data on the `|` character to create an array called `data`

(d) Then create two new vars, un and pw, out of the data array

(e) Place each var where it belongs.

(f) Note that you must use `.val(varname)` (not `.html`) to insert a value into an `<input type="text"` element

(g) Your `<input type="password"` field does not have an ID.  Please add the ID `password` for my code to work:

```
<input type="text" name="password" id="password" >
```

(h) You seem to be confused about your `<input class="search"` field and your `<input id="searchid"` field, because your user is typing in the first field (class="search") but you are calling its value "searchid", *which is the ID of a different input field.*

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and should NOT BE USED ANYMORE. Please advise the usage of `mysqli_*` functions or better use `PDO`.